Finding an Unknown Point of Intersection and an Unknown Angle Based on Polar and Euclidean Coordinates and Circle Geometry
I have the following pictures.


It's supposed to be two concentric circles. The radii of both of the circles are known. There are two rectangle-like shapes; each of them shares a border with one of the circles. I'm referring to them as 'rectangle-like' because they are basically rectangles except one of their sides is actually the arc of the circle it shares a border with. The dashed lines are radii of the circles, and they perfectly bisect both of the rectangle-like shapes. The heights of the two rectangle-like shapes are known and equivalent (they are represented by the green lines in the bottom picture). The 'widths' of the two rectangle-like shapes are also known and equivalent (they are represented by the red lines in the bottom picture). I use the word 'width' loosely here because it is the distance from the middle of the short edge of the shape to the middle of the arc on the opposite side. Because the dashed lines are radii, the red line segments perfectly bisect the green line segments, and they are perpendicular too.
How can I solve for the angle between the two dashed lines and the point of intersection of the two rectangle-like shapes if both radii are known and if the lengths of the red and green line segments are known? Thank you!

Just to be clear -- -the dot you've drawn is to indicate that the bottom-most corner of the upper rectangle lies on the upper side of the lower rectangle, right? If so, this is messy but do-able.

OK. To get started, here's your diagram, redrawn and labelled:

The center of the circle is $Q$; the outer radius is $t$, the inner radius is $r$. I've used $2\ell$ as the length of the box, and $2w$ as the width so that the algebra will work out more nicely.
I've also labelled three points, $A$ (the green dot), $C$, the orangy dot in the middle of the upper rectangle, and $B$, the point where the rectangles intersect. I'm going to do all my work in cartesian coordinates with the origin at $Q$. The key thing you need to know is that if you move in a direction $h$, measured counterclockwise from the positive x-axis, starting at the origin and going a distance $u$, you end up at $(u \cos (h), u \sin (h))$. I've left out the two dotted lines from your picture, but for the lower one the angle is zero, and for the upper one, I'm going to say that the unknown angle is called $h$.
Let's look at point $A$. The red circle is distance $r$ from $Q$, but the vertical line that $A$ is on...well, it's $2\ell$ closer. So the distance from $Q$ to the center of that short vertical line containing $A$ is $r - 2\ell$. That means that the coordinates of that center point are $(r-2\ell, 0)$. The point $A$ is distance $w$ up from there, so
$$
A = (r - 2\ell, w).
$$
Hold that thought.
Now let's do the same thing for $C$: by exactly the same logic, its distance from $Q$ is $t - 2\ell$. But it's along a ray at angle $h$ (which we don't know!), so its coordinates are
$$
C = ( (t-2\ell) \cos(h), (t - 2\ell) \sin(h)).
$$
If we say that $c = \cos(h)$ and $s = \sin(h)$ to simplify things, we have
$$
C = ((t-2\ell)c , (t- 2\ell) s )
$$
And a unit-length arrow pointing from $Q$ to $C$ has coordinates $(c, s)$.
Now you have to take my word for something, which is that if we rotate that arrow clockwise 90 degrees, then the rotated length-1 arrow will point in direction $(s, -c)$. And that means that a length-$w$ arrow (which is what we need to get from $C$ to $B$ must be $(ws, -wc)$. Adding that to the position of $C$, we get that
\begin{align}
B 
&= ((t-2\ell)c, (t-2\ell)s) + (ws, -wc) \\
&= ((t-2\ell)c + ws, (t-2\ell)s - wc) \\
\end{align}
The one thing we know from the picture is that the $y$-coordinate of the point $B$ is the same as the $y$-coordinate of the point $A$, which tells us that
$$
(t-2\ell)s - wc = w
$$
or, restoring the trig stuff,
$$
(t - 2\ell) \sin(h) - w \cos(h) = w
$$
From this, we hope to find $h$ somehow. I'm again going to name something to save typing. Let's give $t-2\ell$ the name $b$, so that we have
$$
b = t - 2\ell \\
b \sin(h) - w \cos(h) = w \tag{1}
$$
Now I'm going to use one of those functions you may not have heard of; it's called atan2. If you have a point $P = (x, y)$ in the plane, and draw a ray from the origin to $P$, that ray makes some angle with the positive x-axis, right? Could be anywhere from -180 to +180 degrees. Well, u = atan2(y, x) [yes, that's the right order!] gets you that angle, although it gives it to you in radians rather than degrees. What that means is that $\cos(u)$ is proportional to $x$, and $\sin(u)$ is proportional to $y$. To say that better, if $u = atan2(y, x)$, then
\begin{align}
x &= \cos(u) \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}\\
y &= \sin(u) \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}.
\end{align}
So what? Well, I'm going to let $u = atan2(b, w)$, where those come from equation (1) up above. And that'll give me
\begin{align}
w &= \cos(u) \sqrt{b^2 + w^2} \\
b &= \sin(u) \sqrt{b^2 + w^2}
\end{align}
Let's plug those into equation 1 to get
$$
\sin(u) \sqrt{b^2 + w^2} \sin(h) - \cos(u) \sqrt{b^2 + w^2} \cos(h) = w 
$$
and then divide through by the square root to get
$$
\sin(u) \sin(h) - \cos(u)\cos(h) = \frac{w}{\sqrt{b^2 + w^2}}.
$$
The sweet thing here is that the left hand side is $-\cos(u+h)$. So we get
$$
\cos(u+h) = -\frac{w}{\sqrt{b^2 + w^2}} \tag{2}
$$
We can apply the inverse of cosine, which folks write $\cos^{-1}$, and which you get on your calculator by pressing "INV" and then "COS", to both sides to get
$$
u + h = \cos^{-1}( -\frac{w}{\sqrt{b^2 + w^2}} )
$$
and so our unknown angle $h$ is just
$$
 h = \cos^{-1}( -\frac{w}{\sqrt{b^2 + w^2}} ) - u.
$$
Let's unravel things a bit. Recall that $b$ was a name for $t - 2\ell$, and $u$ is a name for $atan2(b, w)$,
so this becomes
$$
 h = \cos^{-1}( -\frac{w}{\sqrt{(t-2\ell)^2 + w^2}} ) - atan2(t-2\ell,w).
$$
And that's an answer in terms of the inputs you specified.
I'm going to go ahead and post this answer, and then I'm going to write a little matlab code to be sure I got all the signs and algebra right, and I'll follow up with that in a bit.
Here's code in Matlab to test all this -- it actually seems to work.
function h = MSE5012328(t, r, w, l)
%% Find the angle required by 
%% https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5012328/finding-an-unknown-point-of-intersection-and-an-unknown-angle-based-on-polar-and/5012349#5012349

arg1 = - w / sqrt((t - 2*l)^2 + w^2);
first  = acos(arg1);
b = t - 2*l; 
second = atan2(b, w);
h = first - second;

strcat('answer in degrees is  ', mat2str(180*h/pi))

clf; 
figure(1)
th = linspace(0, 2*pi, 200);
hold on; % do multiple plots on the same axes
plot(t * cos(th), t * sin(th), 'k'); % draw outer circle in black. 
plot(r * cos(th), r * sin(th), 'r'); % draw inner circle in red. 
set(gca, 'DataAspectRatio', [1 1 1]); % prevent matlab from distorting things
%Draw a rough approximation of the box
xs = [(r-2*l) r r (r-2*l) (r-2*l)];
ys = [w w -w -w w];
plot(xs, ys, 'm');
plot([0, xs(1)], [0, 0], 'k--'); % the horizontal dotted line

m = [cos(h) -sin(h); sin(h), cos(h)]; %matrix to rotate by angle h
xs = xs +(t-r); % Move the box in so that its outer edge is at the OUTER circle
pts = [xs; ys];
p = m * pts; 
xp = p(1,:);
yp = p(2,:);
plot(xp, yp, 'g')
plot([0, (xp(1) + xp(4))/2], [0, (yp(1) + yp(4))/2], 'k--'); % the sloped dotted line

When I run this with
MSE5012328(10, 9, 1, 3)

I get this response:
ans =

    'answer in degrees is28.072486935853'


ans =

    0.4900

the second number being in radians. It also produces this picture:

